# Linux API видеопоток

Tags: linux, api

Пытаюсь написать небольшой видео-драйвер. Рисовать линии и прочее понятно как, но как рисовать интерфейс WM? Может есть какие-то функции в Linux API которые отдают пиксели на отрисовку или что-нибудь подобное? Не нашел какие функции за это отвечают Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что такое *видеодрайвер* в вашем понимании?